# How to add Workaccount button in Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I want to know How to integrated AZURE **work account** button on my b2c login screen.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Azure AD accounts.

In that case, you can either use custom policies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom), or apply for private preview of the OpenID Connect provider here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/17699680-add-support-for-a-generic-openid-connect-identity